# How to use function interface, and use it as function argument?

Tags: java

I am not that good with function interface.

How to make `Function<S, Set<S>>` and how to send it as parameter?

```
 public class Algorithms {
    public static <S> Optional<Node<S>> search(S s0, Function<S, Set<S>> succ, Predicate<S> goal) {
        .
        .
        .
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you need the `Function` to do?

Comment: Take object and add it to new copy of existing Set<object>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any interface with exactly one non-default method is a *functional interface,* and `Function` meets that condition. That means you can implement it using a *lambda expression.* For example, let's say we're using this `search` function to search someone's family tree:

```java
search(alice, (person) -> person.getChildren(), (person) -> person.getName().equals("Bob"));
```

The second argument, `(person) -> person.getChildren()`, creates a `Function<Person, Set<Person>>` that calls `getChildren()` on its argument. (We know it should accept a `Person` and return a `Set<Person>` from how we're passing it to `search`.) Likewise, the third argument creates a `Predicate<Person>` that checks if their name is "Bob".

Now, there are two "convenience" features I'm glossing over here. When the lambda only takes one argument (as is the case with both `Function` and `Predicate`), you can omit the parentheses around the name. Secondly, when a lambda only calls some method on its argument, you can use a *method reference,* which is just a more concise way of writing the lambda:

```java
search(alice, Person::getChildren, person -> person.getName().equals("Bob"));
```

That's entirely equivalent, just more concise.

You *can* also implement functional interfaces the "old-school" way, i.e. by writing an (anonymous) class, but lambda syntax avoids a *lot* of boilerplate and is more readable. It's still fundamentally doing the same thing (and your IDE should be able to transform the one to the other, if that's helpful for you).